# AMQP Connection from Azure Service Bus to ReadyAPI

Tags: azure, azureservicebus, amqp, ready-api

I am trying to switch the rest calls from ReadyAPI to our application with AMQP messaging. There is an add-on for ReadyAPI that has the AMQP steps but I need a connection to, I presume, the service bus.
[image: AMQP Connection]

I tried using the service bus as the host name with port: 5671 and 5672 but it gives me an error. Any ideeas how would I connect these two?
Thanks!

Comment: [AMQP outbound port requirements](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-amqp-protocol-guide#amqp-outbound-port-requirements) and [Port 5671 Blocked :(. What are other options?](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/issues/2554)

Comment: I did an nslookup for my servicebus and the ports are open for it so that's not the problem. I also tried to use port 443 which is a bit better(?), for 5671 and 5672 it gives me  the error "null" (yea, that's the whole message). For 443 it gives me a timeout.

Comment: [Service Bus messaging exceptions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-messaging-exceptions#exception-types) and [TimeoutException](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-messaging-exceptions#timeoutexception)

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below points to fix your issue.

- I think this is due to the internal company firewall restriction which blocks all the traffic on port 5671 and 5672.
- So i will recommend you to set your TCP proxy HAProxy on VM.
- This TCP proxy configured in such a way that which route
  all incoming traffic on a specific port azure service end point.
- You can change the end point using `connection.setHostname("");`
- You should also change your port number from 5671 to 8080 in ClientConstants.
- After doing all this traffic will route to TCP proxy endpoint instead of service bus as firewall blocked all traffic on 5671 port.
- For More about this you can follow the official [Microsoft Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/service-bus-messaging/service-bus-amqp-protocol-guide).